# How to implement different behavior for function in anonymous function javascript

Tags: javascript, php, callback, xmlhttprequest

I am new to JavaScript and I want to use `send_request` function twice, but with different behaviour. Element with name `button1` should show response on the element, whereas `button2` not.

```
  function send_request(url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.send('data=test');
    xhr.onload = function () {document.getElementById('reply').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;};
  }
  document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', function() { send_request("/data.php"); });
  document.getElementById('button2').addEventListener('click', function() { send_request("/clear_data.php"); });
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give `send_request` another parameter, a function that's called with the `responseText`, so you could pass one function that assigns to `reply`, and another function that does whatever you want instead:

```
function send_request(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.send('data=test');
  xhr.onload = () => callback(xhr.responseText);
}
document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  send_request("/data.php", (responseText) => {
    document.getElementById('reply').innerHTML = responseText;
  });
});
document.getElementById('bitton2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  send_request("/clear_data.php", (responseText) => {
    console.log('bitton 2 response: ' + responseText);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this, but if we just start with your basic requirement, you could have `send_request` simply take an argument that determines if the element should show the response.

```
function send_request(url, showResponse) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.send('data=test');
    xhr.onload = function () {
      // If showResponse is true, log the response. If not, don't
      showResponse ? document.getElementById('reply').innerHTML = xhr.responseText : null;
    };
  }

  document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', function() { 
    // Call the function and indicate that the response should be shown
    send_request("/data.php", true); 
  });

  document.getElementById('bitton2').addEventListener('click', function() { 
    // Call the function and indicate that the response should not be shown
    send_request("/clear_data.php", false); 
  });
```